# vs code remote ssh: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

I'm using microsoft's remote-ssh extension to connect via ssh to a server.

It suddenly stopped working now with the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I tried to reconnect and reinstall the extension, but I'm still having the same issue.

Thanks for any help